# Populating a new column with a binary variable based on the values of another column in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm new to R and coding in general and I need some help connecting two processes in R.
 I have a dataframe:

```
X <- c(385, 386, 387, 388, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 398, 399, 400)

east<- seq(1,14,1)

north<- seq(1,14,1)

df2 <-data.frame(X,east,north)
```

What I would like to do is to look at the values in X row by row and compare them to each other to populate a new column with a binary result. For example, if X[1,] and X[2,] are sequential  the new column value is 1, if X[1,] and X[2,] are not sequential 0. 
This piece of code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){
ifelse((df2$X[i+1]-df2$X[i] <= 1), print(1), print(0))
}
```

provides the info that I want, but I am struggling to get it into a column.

```
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 0
[1] 1
[1] 1
```

I have also tried this:

```
df2$response <- NA
for(i in 1:nrow(df2)){
if(df2$X[i+1]-df2$X[i]==1){df2$response[i]<-1} else
if(df2$X[i+1]-df2$X[i]>1){df2$response[i]<-0}
}
```

but received this error:

```
Error in if (df2$X[i + 1] - df2$X[i] == 1) { : 
 missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any suggestions? Tips? Thank you!

Comment: Oops let me try that dataframe again:

Comment: Cannot have i+1 index at the last row of the dataframe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're almost there.

```
df2$flag <- ifelse(c(diff(df2$X), 1) <= 1, 1, 0)
```

Comment: No need to use `ifelse`, you can just use `df2$flag <- 1*(c(diff(df2$X), 1) <= 1)`

Comment: Both of those will inappropriately recycle the first value to be the last.

Comment: how do you know the last `flag` is `1`?

Comment: This "solution" actually delivers whatever the first flag was. Recycling. (_Should_ have given a warning.)

Answer (score 4):

People are getting tied up in knots with arcane solutions. Just:

```
df2$response <- c( head( df2$X, -1) - tail(df2$X, -1) <= 1, NA_integer_)
```

OR:

```
df2$response <-  c( diff(df2$X) <= 1, NA_integer_ )
```

Need the NA to account for the fact that at the last row there is nothing to subtract. Using NA_integer_ as the placeholder rather than NA results in coercion of the logical values to integer (NA by default is logical type).

Comment: You'll probably want to add a parenthesis to your second answer

Answer (score 2):

To wrap it up, `data.table` solution (just for illustration)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[, flag := c(diff(X) <= 1, NaN)]
```

Comment: What is with this fascination with `ifelse`? More simply: `setDT(df2)[, flag := c( diff(X) > 1, NaN)]`

Comment: @BondedDust, that will result in an opposite output where `1`s will be replaced by `0` and vice versa

Comment: Oh. OK but switching the sign will fix, won't it?

Comment: @BondedDust, OK switched to your version :)

Answer (score 1):

#### Another option using `dplyr`:

```
 require(dplyr)

 df2 %>% mutate( flag = ifelse( lead(X)-X==1, 1, 0 ) )
```

but `ifelse()` doesn't scale well / can be slow, so we could do:

```
 df2 %>% mutate( flag = as.integer( lead(X)-X==1 ) )
```

where the `as_integer()` is necessary to specify exactly the output you've put forth as it converts `TRUE` and `FALSE` to `1` and `0`, respectively.

```
#      X flag
# 1  385    1
# 2  386    1
# 3  387    1
# 4  388    0
# 5  390    1
# 6  391    1
# 7  392    1
# 8  393    1
# 9  394    1
# 10 395    1
# 11 396    0
# 12 398    1
# 13 399    1
# 14 400   NA
```

Comment: The default registration is off. the value for row 1 was supposed to be 1.

Comment: @BondedDust thanks, fixed. I really shouldn't stackoverflow _?verb_ when I'm sleep + caffeine deprived.

Comment: I figured this case had a solution, but I've not yet dug into pkg:dplyr. It does appear to be worth  breaking out my shovel though.

Comment: Now that you have fixed the registration it's time to fix the entirely superfluous `ifelse`: Try : `df2 %>% mutate( flag = lead(X)-X==1 )`

Comment: @BondedDust I had not done this because of how OP specified the intended output. edited with `as_integer` wrap though. thanks. ahem again.

Comment: And as it turned out,  he accepted an answer that wasn't correct. Oh well.